# Can FileTransfer be used to target remote FTP servers?

Tags: 7

I need to send files to a remote server within an ajax callback.
Snooping around Drupal's includes, I came across the FileTransfer class, but I haven't fully understood the concept of its access limit to $jail (defaults to Drupal's root).
Is it possible to use this class to access remote FTP directories as well?
If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What used for the `$jail` parameter is the directory for which the operations are limited; if you try deleting a file outside that directory, the operation is not allowed.

If you want FTP access to a directory on a remote site, you should use the [FileTransferFTP](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--filetransfer--ftp.inc/class/FileTransferFTP/7) class, and create an instance with [FileTransferFTP::factory()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--filetransfer--ftp.inc/function/FileTransferFTP%3a%3afactory/7).